# Should I always check if a variable was changed, or just change it regardless?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code (Javascript):

```
var boolA = false;
var boolB = Math.random()*2 ? true : false;
```

I don't know if boolB will be true or false, but I need to update boolA with it anyway every tick. Should I just update it or check if it was changed?

Which is fastest?

```
boolA = boolB;
```

or

```
if ( boolB != boolA ) boolA = boolB;
```

What about integers, strings and other objects?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why not try it? Do it a million times and see which takes the longest? Just remember to do it in every JavaScript engine in the wild.

Comment: You can try it here: http://jsperf.com/

Comment: Not really related to the question, but won't `Math.random()*2` almost always evaluate to `true`? The only time it won't is when `Math.random()` results in precisely `0`. But maybe that's what you want, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Straight assignment will always be fastest.